# Cannot connect Dell D430 to Samsung LCD TV via VGA cable

Tags: lcd, dell-latitude

For some reason I can't get my Dell D430 to show on a Samsung LCD TV. This works fine on a newer dell laptops (E6400). I've updated bios and display drivers from dell. Yes I know this is an old computer, but it's small and perfect as HTPC. If I get it to work that is.

Comment: I was never able to figure this one out. Ended up using another computer.

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you using? If it's Windows 7, press the `Windows key` and `P` and check if the output is at the right place.

It should be set to (I think it's) *clone* or just *your TV*.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the VGA out in the back to connect to your tv or monitor, and that the vga cable is ok (same cable worked with your friend's laptop).
For the Dell 430, you toggle the vga output by hitting `<Fn> <F8>` (at the same time) to "switch the video image between the display only, the external device only, or the display and the external device simultaneously." Be sure and give it a several seconds between each mode, to allow the video to sync up. Some BIOS have override options to video out (like disabling it when on battery power), so be sure its connected to an AC adapter before its powered on.
This PC is far from old and should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

As well as the above, check the numeric buttons at the top of the keyboard - they will probably have little symbols showing another function. If there is one that looks like a screen, hold down the fn button and press that button a few times, waiting around 10 secs between pressing it again.

Also try dropping resolution to 640x480 before this, if you get it working, gradually increase the resolution until it cuts out.